# How do you use RightJS widgets within an existing JQuery app?

Tags: jquery, rightjs

Well, title pretty much asks it all:  How do you use RightJS widgets within an existing JQuery app?

I've been looking over RightJS and I especially like like the Billboard and Sliderwidgets and would like to use them in an existing app, but I am not finding a clear to use the two libraries (JQuery and RightJS) side-by-side.

Does anyone have an example or best practice that they would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

RightJS has a safe-mode build, just hook it up when you need to use RightJS alongside with some other libraries. RightJS UI widgets work with both normal and safe-mode builds.

*NOTE* in safe mode all the helper methods in RightJS are available through the `RightJS` object